# PUT method Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring

I'm trying to use the following format for making a put request through the RESTtemplate.

```
 @Autowired
 RestTemplate template;

 @RequestMapping(value = "/change", method = RequestMethod.PUT)
 public ModelAndView change(Data data){


     List<MediaType> acceptableMediaTypes = new ArrayList<MediaType>();
     acceptableMediaTypes.add(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML);

     HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
     headers.setAccept(acceptableMediaTypes);

     HttpEntity<Data> entity = new HttpEntity<Data>(data, headers);
     String url="http://www...com";



     try {
        template.put(url, entity);

      } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);
      }

  return new ModelAndView("redirect:/home");
 }
```

I checked on the database and I realized that there is no change. Even the request is not written on the log file. When I'm debugging, I am not getting any error. Probably I'm not using correctly the put method. Can anyone suggest me how should I use the put method or what else should I try to perform a put request with the RestTemplate?

Also i try to use the exchange method instead of the put:

```
    try {
        ResponseEntity<Data> result = template.exchange(Url, HttpMethod.PUT, entity, Data.class);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
```

But in this case i'm taking the following exception:

org.springframework.web.client.RestClientException: Could not extract response: no suitable HttpMessageConverter found for response type [website.Data] and content type [text/html;charset=utf-8].

As you can see from the headers i set the content type as application/xml and not text/html. I look at the headers and i can see that contained:

```
Accept: application/xml
```

I really can't understand. What else should i change? Any comments on the exception?

Configuration:

```
<bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.ResourceBundleViewResolver" 
p:basename="config/views" p:order="1" />

<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.ControllerClassNameHandlerMapping"/>

<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.XmlViewResolver">
    <property name="location">
        <value>/WEB-INF/classes/config/xml-views.xml</value>
    </property>
    <property name="order" value="0" />
</bean>
<!--It is used for redirect-->
<bean id="urlBasedViewResolver"
      class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">
    <property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView"/>
    <property name="prefix" value=""/>
    <property name="suffix" value=""/>
    <property name="order" value="2" />
</bean>    

<context:annotation-config />
<!--<context:annotation-config />-->
<context:component-scan base-package="data.controller" />
<context:component-scan base-package="data.service" />


 <bean id="restTemplate"  class="org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate">
    <property name="messageConverters"> 
        <list>
            <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.xml.SourceHttpMessageConverter"/>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Comment: So, when you debug, you're able to get into the change method?

Comment: yes but it doesn't give any error.Am I using the put method correctly? Is there any other way to perform a put request?

Comment: Can you debug the side that the template is sending to? Is that side getting the message? Or is it something you don't have access to?

Comment: I don't have access.So thats the reason that i'm trying to take a message or an error message

Comment: You might try the exchange method instead and see what the ResponseEntity tells you, if anything. Perhaps you'll get a status code that might illuminate more. I'm still a little confused as to how you can not have access to the other service but then check a database to see if something changed?

Comment: The server side implements the rest approach so it offers to me links, and when i change smt i can see the changes on the url's. When i tried with exchange i could perform a POST request but i couldn't perform a PUT request. When i tried the put request with the exchange i took a RestClientException which says: Could not extract response: no suitable HttpMessageConverter found for response type [webpage.Data] and content type [text/html;charset=utf-8]

Comment: Hmm, not sure about that. You could try setting the responseType field to null and have the response variable be of type ResponseEntity<?> -- that might at least let you see the HTTP details. Also, can you try the PUT request in a browser via something like a Rest Client plugin, just to see if you can get it to work that way? You might get better feedback from it, too.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/13471/discussion-between-nick-robertson-and-ahungerartist)

Comment: Could you give us the Spring MVC configuration plz?

Comment: Yes of course.I already update my answer.

Comment: What is the server you are deploying to ?

Comment: Do you mean to have any annotation on the `data` parameter on that method?  Something like `@RequestBody` or `@RequestParam`?

Answer (score 3):

I guess the client of your application is a web-page (then HTML). [This article](http://blog.springsource.com/2009/03/08/rest-in-spring-3-mvc/) explain what to do for your webapp to be ready for the future browsers compatibility (if they decide later to support e.g PUT, DELETE operations).

In summary for our project we just declared these line in the web.xml:

```xml
<filter>
    <filter-name>hiddenHttpMethodFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>hiddenHttpMethodFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/app/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

The article talk about javascript to add (probably for version prior to Spring 3.0 M1), but we found this solution better as it is just a configuration.